# useEffect and SocketIO Infinite Rerendering, why is it happening?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-router-v4, react-hooks

I am getting data, using useEffect Hook from sockets. Every time I get the response, one particular component rerenders, but I don't pass any socket data to that component.

Code:

```
  const App = () => {
  const isMounted = React.useRef(false);
  const [getSocketData, setSocketData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[App.js] Mounted!');
    isMounted.current = true;
    const socket = socketIOClient(process.env.REACT_APP_BOARD);
    socket.on('ServersInfo', (data) => {
      if (isMounted.current) {
        setSocketData([...data]);
      }
    });
    socket.on('connect_error', () => {
      if (isMounted.current) {
        setSocketData([]);
      }
      console.log('Connection error!');
    });
    return (() => {
      isMounted.current = false;
      socket.disconnect();
      console.log('[App.js] unmounted');
    });
  }, []);

  const routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={['/', '/users/:id']} exact component={() => <MainPage axiosInstance={axiosInstance} />} />
      <Route path='/servers' render={(spProps) => <ServerPing {...spProps} />} />
      <Route render={(nfProps) => <NotFoundComponent {...nfProps} />} />
      {/* <Redirect to='/' /> */}
    </Switch>
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Layout>
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
          {routes}
        </Suspense>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

---

What my Components look like:
- App.js
- Layout (doesn't rerender) (which has 3 children) - MainPage (rerenders infinitely), ServerPing (doesn't rerender), NotFoundComponent (doesn't rerender)

The question is: why MainPage Component rerenders infinitely?
I mean MainPage Component and its children unmount and mount again, when socket data fetches which is weird behaviour.

MainPageComponent:

```
const MainPage = ({ axiosInstance, ...props }) => {

  const isMounted = React.useRef(false);
  const [loadingPage, setLoadingPage] = useState(true);
  const [usernames, setUsernames] = useState([]);
  const [currentDay] = useState(new Date().getDay());

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    console.log('[MainPage.js] Mounted!');
    getUsers();
    return () => {
      console.log('[MainPage.js] Unmounted!');
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  const getUsers = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axiosInstance.get('/users');
      const newData = await res.data;
      const newArray = [];
      newData.map(user => (
        newArray.push({id: user._id, flag: user.flag, text: user.name, value: user.name.toLowerCase()})
      ));
      if (isMounted.current) {
        setUsernames(newArray);
        setLoadingPage(false);
      }
    } catch {
      if (isMounted.current) {
        setLoadingPage(false);
      }
    }
  };

  return...
```

Comment: Do you have code snippet for `MainPage`? where is `axiosInstance` defined?

Comment: @Kunukn uploaded the snippet. But I guess axiosInstance is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are using `component` prop instead of `render` prop to `render the MainPage` which will remount the component on any re-render of App component if there is a callback given to a component prop.

Below code should fix the issue

```
<Route 
    path={['/', '/users/:id']} 
    exact 
    render={(props) => <MainPage {...props} axiosInstance={axiosInstance} />} 
/>
```

According to the react-router-dom docs

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
>   router uses `React.createElement` to create a new React element from the
>   given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
>   component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
>   results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
>   mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
>   an inline function for inline rendering, use the `render` or the
>   `children` prop (below).